Get only explicit parameters for constructor of an inner class
The docs on the constructor.getParameterTypes() method says this:

... Note that the constructors of some inner classes may have an implicitly declared parameter in addition to explicitly declared ones.

As it says, I tried to use it for an inner class with a parameterless constructor and it gave me a constructor with one parameter (the enclosing class, an example below). Is there any easy way to only get the explicit parameters?
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class TestInner{

    public class Inner{}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName("TestInner$Inner");
        Constructor<?>[] constructors = innerClass.getConstructors();
        String str = Arrays.stream(constructors).map(TestInner::stringifyConstructor).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    public static String stringifyConstructor(Constructor c){
        return "("+Arrays.stream(c.getParameterTypes()).map(e->e.getName()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))+")";
    }
}

I understand that I can just remove the first element, but how would I know if the first element is 100% implicit? It seems that not all inner classes have this parameter (because the docs say "some inner classes may" and inner classes if I understand correctly mean non-static nested classes). Is there any other factor (besides for not being static) that can cause this parameter to not be there?

I am guessing here, but perhaps there is no requirement for an inner class to receive a reference to its containing instance, if that isn't actually going to be used?

@AndyTurner, in the OP's example, TestInner$Inner does nothing that requires the containing instance of TestInner, but my Java compiler still gives it a default constructor that takes a TestInner as a parameter, as described.

@JohnBollinger that is what I would expect; but my question was whether it is required. Reading the spec subsequently, I noticed that it says it is required, to enable compatibility with other compilers.

As John Bollinger's answer says, non-private inner member classes are mandated by the spec to have an extra parameter representing the enclosing instance.
In JLS 15.9.5.1, some anonymous classes are mandated to have such an extra parameter too.
This does not apply to other kinds of inner classes (e.g. private inner member classes, local classes), so the compiler implementation is free to pass the enclosing instance in any way it wants. The compiler implementation can choose to not use an extra parameter altogether. This is why the documentation says "some inner classes".
A static class is not an inner class, so being static is not a reason for not having an extra parameter representing the enclosing instance.
For the extra parameter that is mandated by the spec (for non-private inner member classes), they can be checked using isImplicit. This checks for the ACC_MANDATED access flag, which indicates that the parameter is implicitly declared in source code as mandated by the spec.
If a compiler implementation chooses to pass the enclosing instance using an extra parameter for the other kinds of inner classes, that extra parameter will be synthetic (an implementation artefact), and you can check this with isSynthetic. This checks for the ACC_SYNTHETIC access flag, which indicates that the parameter is neither implicitly nor explicitly declared in source code.
For more details on access flags, see JVMS 4.7.24.
As for your practical problem of producing a string description of the constructor, a reasonable solution is to just exclude any parameter that is mandated or synthetic.
public static String stringifyConstructor(Constructor<?> c){
    return "("+
            Arrays.stream(c.getParameters())
                    .filter(p -> !p.isSynthetic() && !p.isImplicit())
                    .map(p -> p.getType().getName())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) +
            ")";
}

Of course, these access flags can be added for reasons other than passing enclosing instances, but in those cases you likely don't want them in your string description anyway :)
getParameters reads the MethodParameters attribute, which is an optional attribute. If the compiler chooses not to emit this attribute, this will not work. In that case you might want to fallback to just outputting all the parameter types.

I tried this and it seems it only works if the java file is compiled using the -parameters jvm option

"The compiler implementation can choose to not use an extra parameter altogether" this isn't true. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se23/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1 describes whether or not the constructor receives an extra parameter - specifically for anonymous classes. What I suspect the compiler can choose is whether to retain that extra parameter.

@Awes I tried it on javac 22 and it works every time without -parameter. But you are right - the MethodParameters attribute can be absent in a class file, which I overlooked. In that case there is no way to determine this.

When I declare a constructor like public Inner(TestInner TestInner.this) {} I wouldn’t consider the parameter “implicit” anymore but it seems, this is not the meaning of “implicit”, Reflection is using…

@Holger Oh so that' what the syntax is! I considered the case of explicitly writing the enclosing instance parameter! I tried a bunch of different syntaxes and couldn't get it to compile, so I thought that you just can't write this explicitly lol.

You can, since Java 8, to be able to add annotations. You can even declare the ordinary this, for example public class Inner {  public Inner(TestInner TestInner.this) {}  @Override public String toString(Inner this) {  return super.toString();  }  }

@Holger Oh is this the same feature as the "redundant" this parameter? In that case I would agree that it is not explicit. That's not really a formal parameter of the constructor. It's almost just a comment.

@Sweeper Do you know how one might check if an Executable (Method or Comstructor) contains the MethodParameters attribute?

For completeness, javac generates the MethodParameters for inner class constructors, even if -parameters was not specified since JDK 21, see JDK-8292275

@Holger I'm using java 17

"In JLS 15.9.5.1, anonymous classes are mandated to have such an extra parameter too" -- not exactly.  That section specifies that some anonymous classes' constructors get the extra parameter, but others don't.  According to the JLS, it depends on the nature of the superclass.  Its rule breaks down to the anonymous constructor getting the extra parameter if instances of its superclass have enclosing instances.  Notably with respect to this question, JLS does not condition it on whether the anonymous class itself is declared in static context.

@JohnBollinger That line was added in response to Andy Turner's first comment about anonymous classes, and in hindsight that is indeed quite badly written.

It is true that JLS 15.9.5.1 applies only to anonymous classes, but not true that the JLS says nothing about inner classes other than those and non-private inner member classes.  For classes that get a default constructor assigned, JLS specifies fully which which classes' default constructors should get the implicit extra parameter and which not. Also, it is true that the JLS allows implementations to do what they want for declared constructors of local classes and private inner member classes, but it seems unlikely in practice that they would do differently than for default constructors.


how would I know if the first element is 100% implicit? It seems that
not all inner classes have this parameter (because the docs say "some
inner classes may" and inner classes if I understand correctly mean
non-static nested classes). Is there any other factor (besides for not
being static) that can cause this parameter to not be there?

Programmatic determination
In principle, you can look at the Parameter objects returned by Constructor.getParameters() to determine programmatically which constructor parameters are defined explicitly in Java code, which are defined implicitly according to the Java language specifications, and which are synthesized wholly at the discretion of the Java implementation (see below).  As documented from at least Java 8, Parameter.isImplicit() will return true if and only if the reflected parameter is implicitly declared, as specified by the JLS. Parameter.isSynthetic() will return true if and only if the reflected parameter is neither explicitly nor implicitly declared.
In practice, however, some Java compilers do not emit the metadata needed for those isImplicit() and isSynthetic() methods to work correctly.  In particular, OpenJDK had a longtime bug in this area, fixed only relatively recently, in OpenJDK 21.  If you cannot rely on your classes to have been compiled by a compiler that provides the needed metadata that that leaves you up a creek, because the language spec does not provide an exhaustive list of conditions under which constructors get such an extra parameter.
Per spec
The JLS gives rules for some of those extra parameters:

The constructor of a non-private inner member class implicitly declares, as the first formal parameter, a variable representing the immediately enclosing instance of the class[.]

(JLS 23, section 8.8.1)
If the class has no declared constructors and is not an anonymous class,

The default constructor has no formal parameters, except in a non-private inner member class, where the default constructor implicitly declares one formal parameter representing the immediately enclosing instance of the class[.]

(JLS 23, section 8.8.9)
The rationale given in section 8.8.1 is a bit technical, but it boils down to whether the class of the containing instance might be compiled by a different compiler than the inner class itself is.
And if the class is an anonymous class, the form of its anonymous constructor depends on the nature of its superclass, S:


If S is not an inner class, or if S is a local class that occurs in a static context, then the anonymous constructor has one
formal parameter for each actual argument to the class instance
creation expression [...] that declares C.

[...]

Otherwise, the first formal parameter of the anonymous constructor represents the value of the immediately enclosing instance of i with
respect to S (§15.9.2). The type of this parameter is the class type
that immediately encloses the declaration of S.
The anonymous constructor has an additional formal parameter for
each actual argument to the class instance creation expression that
declared the anonymous class.



(JLS 23, section 15.9.5.1)
The specs do not specify that declared constructors of inner classes that are private member classes or local classes get the implicit extra parameter.
Note also that there are nested classes that are not inner classes: those that are explicitly declared static, nested enum and record classes, and all (directly) nested classes of interfaces.  These are the static nested classes, and their constructors do not get an implicit extra parameter because instances of such classes have no containing instance.
Additionally, not all inner classes provide for an enclosing instance, either.  The defining semantic characteristic of inner classes is that instances have access to the runtime context of their definition.  Those that have an enclosing instance have it because that runtime context includes it, but inner classes defined in static context do not have such an instance.
IRL
The JLS defines the syntax and semantics of the Java language, but it does not directly or fully specify how Java implementations must represent that in Java class files.  In order to implement Java language semantics on top of the Java VM, Java compilers can and do synthesize classes, fields, methods, and parameters beyond those specified by the JLS.  Ordinarily, these are transparent to Java programs, but you can expect to be able to observe them via reflection.
Thus, although the spec explicitly says that the default constructors of private member classes and local classes have no parameters (for example), that is a matter of Java semantics, not a constraint on implementations ability to synthesize such a parameter for their own purposes.  The main constraint of that kind is that Java compilers must create class files that run and produce the JLS-required behavior on every conforming JVM of suitable version.
Experimentation with various versions of OpenJDK, the Java reference implementation, show that all tested versions in fact do produce one-parameter default constructors for private inner member classes.  They also produce the extra parameter for local and anonymous classes of instance methods, regardless of the nature of the superclass.  They do not produce the extra parameter for local and anonymous classes declared in static methods except (presumably; not tested) if the direct superclass is an inner class other than a local class declared in static context.
The rule as implemented, then, seems to be that

local classes and anonymous classes not declared in static context get the extra parameter.

declared and default constructors of private inner member classes get the extra parameter, just like those of non-private inner member classes do.

overall, all constructors of classes declared outside static context get the extra parameter, whereas the constructors of classes declared in static context do not. Some of those extra parameters are mandated by the JLS, and others are wholly synthetic.


That is a fine and sensible way to do things.  It is simpler and more consistent than parsimoniously providing only those parameters, including implicit ones, that the JLS specifically requires.  In practice, you probably will not run into an implementation that does things differently. However, the specs provide no basis for relying on that.

I tested my example using a private inner class and constructor.getDeclaredConstructors() and it still added that extra parameter. Did I misunderstand what you said or something else?

@Awes, I tested your example with a private inner class, with two different versions of Java, and I did not get the extra parameter.  And language analogous to what I quoted from JLS 23 appears at least as far back as JLS 8.  I'm inclined to guess, therefore, that you did not perform the test you think you did, because if you did, and if you got the result you describe, then your Java compiler is non-compliant. Default constructors of private inner member classes should have zero parameters.

I'm using java 17.0.10. Did you use innerClass.getDeclaredConstructors() instead of innerClass.getConstructors()? All I changed was public to private on line 7 and getConstructors to getDeclaredConstructors on line 11. If yes, I may be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what it is

@Awes I copied and pasted your code from the question, and replaced public with private for class Inner.  No other changes.  And FWIW, JLS 17 has the same provisions around this issue as the other specifications.  Do make sure you are testing class versions built from the revised source -- one way or another of failing to do this seems a more likely explanation than your compiler behaving contrary to spec.

The method I called to get the constructors, class.getConstructors(), only returns publicly accessible constructors. You have to change it to class.getDeclaredConstructors() to also get the private constructors (it seems this is also needed to get the default constructor for a private member class). Also, if nothing is printed, that means that no constructors are found; the correct result should be an empty pair of parentheses. Are you getting an empty pair of parentheses?

According to jls 8.8.9, the default constructor of a class has the same access as the class itself. I tested in a new java 17 compiler and in java 23 and both gave me the implicit parameter.
Also, it seems from here that "except" here only means that it isn't required, but not that it must not have. Would checking for a this$n private field work though? I wonder if it would be defined in a compiler implementation that leaves out the implicit parameter.

Ok, @Awes, with the modification you describe, I can replicate your results.  I have updated this answer with a discussion of the discrepancy between spec and (OpenJDK) implementation.

The explanation of the rationale in 8.8.1 says that when the “class is necessarily emitted by the same compiler as the class instance creation expression” then “that compiler can represent the immediately enclosing instance how ever it wishes” and the representation chosen is a synthetic constructor parameter and I can’t imagine any other feasible strategy. But the difference is, if parameter metadata is included in the class file, the parameter of the non-private class’s constructor is marked “implicit” while the other is marked “synthetic”.

@Holger, rationale is not normative.  It can guide interpretation of the spec where that is ambiguous, but the spec is not ambiguous about whether default constructors of private member classes get the extra parameter.  And this is visible to programs (hence this question), so it matters if implementations fail to conform.  Moreover, that the constructors of local and anonymous classes observably do not get the extra parameter suggests that that should be a feasible alternative for private member classes, too.

@Holger, I'm inclined to think that the observed inconsistency would be better characterized as a flaw in the spec than as a flaw in implementations, but either way, there is definitely a flaw, at least for the default constructors.

Did you actually verify that local or anonymous classes do not have an extra parameter? I mean, I can’t imagine how they would work without, as you can access the surrounding instance in all of them.

Yes, @Holger, I did verify that the default constructors of local and anonymous classes did not get the extra parameter.  I used a variation on the code posted in the question that tested a private member class, a local class, and an anonymous class all in the same run.  The default constructor of the private member class had the extra parameter.  The default constructors of the other two did not.

Hmm, https://ideone.com/RusjsN

@Holger, https://ideone.com/JWBIPy

Yeah, when you declare them in a static method where no surrounding instance exists, there is no parameter for the surrounding instance. So the, not very surprising, conclusion is that whenever a surrounding instance exist, there will be a parameter, mandated or synthetic, to pass the instance to the constructor.

Fair point, @Holger, and I have revised this answer in light of your findings.  Which, unfortunately, reveal more deviations from the JLS. I think this is most likely an issue of the spec failing to accurately capture its intent, rather than implementations wantonly doing as they please, but that is still a serious problem.

Note that the cited part(s) talk about formal parameters. Others can always exist, e.g. to pass captured values. In this regard, the only violation I see, is that in case of local classes, the parameter should be marked “synthetic” rather than “mandated” (aka “implicit”). And this information is not even included in most class files.

Yes, @Holger, the JLS puts it in terms of formal parameters.  And as far as the JLS is concerned, this is a distinction from receiver parameters, not from implicit parameters (since JLS refers to some of these as formal parameters), and certainly not from wholly synthetic parameters, which the JLS does not discuss at all, as they are not part of the Java language.  But I acknowledge that implementations are permitted to synthesize parameters that are not even implicitly declared, and that in practice, it is to be expected that these will be visible via reflection.

Answer revised.

If you look into Parameter class you can see list of its fields:

name
modifiers (there is no corresponding modifier in Modifier class)
executable (reference to Method or Constructor)
index
parameterTypeCache
parameterClassCache
declaredAnnotations

None of them contains information you looking for.
Neither do Constructor.
So there is no direct way to tell.
You have to check if class is static and if not, then remove first parameter.

It's more complicated than just whether the class is static.

@JohnBollinger what is other conditions?

See my answer :-)

So it is other rules for anonymous inner classes and classes declared in methods? Are the other cases?

Those, and private member classes that are not declared static.
